# Condition variables program works for 2 threads but not for 3

Tags: c, multithreading

So I  have this program that has 2 threads to increment from 0 to 100 a variable, and it works fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>

int contor;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *incrementare(void *args) {
    int id = (int)args;
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (contor >= 100) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        while (contor %2 == id) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
        }

        contor++;
        printf("Thread %d increment: %d\n",id,contor);


        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t th1, th2,th3;

    if(pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)0) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)1) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(2);
    }


    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is something like:

```
Thread 1 increment: 1
Thread 0 increment: 2
Thread 1 increment: 3
Thread 0 increment: 4
Thread 1 increment: 5
Thread 0 incre.. and so on ,which is nice.
```

But the problem is when I try with 3 threads, and it no longer works as they then come randomly. I only made 3 changes and I do not know what the issue is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>

int contor;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *incrementare(void *args) {
    int id = (int)args;
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (contor >= 100) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        while (contor %3 == id) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
        }

        contor++;
        printf("Thread %d increment: %d\n",id,contor);


        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t th1, th2,th3;

    if(pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)0) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)1) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&th3, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)2) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(3);
    }



    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);
        pthread_join(th3, NULL);


    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    return 0;
}
```

It should do the same right? Only with 3 now. Why isn't it working? This is how it works

```
Thread 2 increment: 1
Thread 2 increment: 2
Thread 1 increment: 3
Thread 1 increment: 4
Thread 2 increment: 5
Thread 1 increment: 6
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you declare a function to return a value, you should really return a value. Even if you ignore the returned value.

Comment: Also unrelated to your problem, but the [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function doesn't return `-1` on error. On success it returns `0` otherwise it returns the error code. That means your check for error is wrong.

Comment: With same level priority tasks OS schedule the threads the way the kernel likes. If you want to impose a specific sequence you should code the constrain.

Comment: If you change `while (contor %3 == id)` to `while (contor %3 != id)`, all three threads *should* participate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the threads to guarantee a cycle, you need to make a thread wait until the counter modulo N (thread count) is a *specific* id, not until it is anything *but* that specific id. With two ids, if it wasn't one, it must be the other. But with three, there are two cases of breaking, and one case of waiting. 
The scheduler is freely capable of choosing whichever of those two spare threads it wants to release.

But if you change this:

```
while (contor %3 == id)
```

to this:

```
while (contor %3 != id)
```

you will enforce that the given thread will *only* write values that are modulo its id.

**However, this isn't enough**. You also need to wake *all* waiters. Before, when you had only two threads, there was always the same waiter: the "other guy" that wasn't the active thread. This a `pthread_cond_signal` would be directed to a specific target thread (the only one not running) and it naturally was also the next one in line.

With three or more threads, there is the possibility that the single thread potentially awoken by `pthread_cond_signal` may not be the one that has has a contor modulo N id. In fact, the more threads you have, the more likely this will happen. In that case, the thread goes back to waiting, but no one else waiting is started up again. You do NOT want to leave this to chance. Make sure *all* the waiters are awoken to ensure the one that is next will get the signal.

Do *not* address this by just sending another `pthread_cond_signal` somewhere. Rather, send a broadcast instead: Change this:

```
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

to this:

```
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
```

This will ensure *all* actively waiting threads eventually get a crack at looking at `contor` and the one that matches `contor` modulo N will get the chance to bump, print, send the next broadcast, and head back to waiting.

Thus, the minimal change to your code would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>      // added for intptr_t
#include<inttypes.h>    // added for printf formatter for intptr_t
#include<pthread.h>

int contor;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *incrementare(void *args) {
    intptr_t id = (intptr_t)args; // proper way to pass an integer via thread param
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (contor >= 100) {
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        while (contor %3 != id) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
        }

        contor++;
        printf("Thread %"PRIdPTR " increment: %d\n",id,contor);


        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL; // should always have well-defined return value
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t th1, th2,th3;

    if(pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)0) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)1) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&th3, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)2) < 0) {
        perror("Error!\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);
    pthread_join(th3, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is below:

```
Thread 0 increment: 1
Thread 1 increment: 2
Thread 2 increment: 3
Thread 0 increment: 4
Thread 1 increment: 5
Thread 2 increment: 6
Thread 0 increment: 7
Thread 1 increment: 8
Thread 2 increment: 9
Thread 0 increment: 10
....
Thread 0 increment: 97
Thread 1 increment: 98
Thread 2 increment: 99
Thread 0 increment: 100
Thread 1 increment: 101
Thread 2 increment: 102
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcac46b4d1e7d42c)

The extra two output are because the code checking the the ceiling-break condition is *before* the cvar-predicate loop. It should be *after*, but I leave that for you to address.

Keep in mind, however, that doing this ultimately defeats the purpose of turning multiple threads loose on a task. Ideally you want *any* thread available to perform work to actually do so. That your work affects just a single global somewhat defeats the real purpose of threading (obviously you would not use threading to count to 100; a single thread in a loop is ideal for that).

---

Regardless, a condensed version of your program appears below. Change the values of `N_THREADS` and `N_COUNT` to see differences in output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N_THREADS 7
#define N_COUNT   100

int contor;  // 0

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *incrementare(void *args)
{
    intptr_t id = (intptr_t)args;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(1)
    {
        while (contor < N_COUNT && contor % N_THREADS != id)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

        if (contor == N_COUNT)
            break;

        printf("Thread %"PRIdPTR" increment: %d\n", id, ++contor);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t ar[N_THREADS];
    intptr_t id = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<N_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        if(pthread_create(ar+i, NULL, &incrementare, (void *)id++) < 0) {
            perror("Error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N_THREADS; ++i)
        pthread_join(ar[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried your first solution, but it dind't work.It gives Thread 0 increment: 1 and then stops, actually it does nothing, somehow stays in infinite cycle.

Comment: @HopelessWanderer yeah, I neglected to mention the need to change your signal to a broadcast. The reasons are important. Read the updated answer.